# JBoss Fuse licensing query

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse

does anyone know how licensing works for JBoss Fuse in a DR environment - say for example we need an active AMQ container running in DR with replicated db, would this count towards the core licensing?

If so is there any way to have anything other than cold DR without a license impact.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, JBoss Fuse is not licensed.  One would purchase an entitlement/subscription from Red Hat.  An entitlement allows access to both the software and technical support.  There is a 'self-supported' entitlement that provides access to the documentation and the knowledge base and software, but does not include the ability to open a support case.

There is no restrictions on the number of deployments with an entitlement.

- Doug